# ListView with Custom Adapter with textview and spinner not able to get data

Tags: android, android-listview, android-spinner, android-adapter

I have a ListView which has a custom adapter. Each row in the list has 3 textfields and a spinner. I need to get the associated data in the textview once the user selects a spinner item.
So imagine as follows the listView : |texView|textView|textView|Spinner|
On selecting something in the spinner column, I need to get the 3 textview data. But I am not able to achieve this.

I am going crazy about how to get this working. Here is the CustomAdapter Code :

```
private class ViewHolder {

   Spinner rateSpinner;
   TextView pView;
   TextView nView;
   TextView cView;

 }


 @Override
 public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

 ViewHolder holder = null;


 if (convertView == null) {
    LayoutInflater vi =       
          (LayoutInflater)getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    convertView = vi.inflate(R.layout.todolist_item, null);

    holder = new ViewHolder();
    holder.pView = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.r1);
    holder.nView = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.r2);
    holder.cView = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.r3); 
    holder.rateSpinner = (Spinner)convertView.findViewById(R.id.spinner2);


    convertView.setTag(holder);

    holder.rateSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(
       new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
           @Override
           public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {
               Object item = parent.getItemAtPosition(pos);


               selectedRating = item.toString();

               Log.v("Chosen rating from spinner", selectedRating); //<-this works correctly

               Log.v("**********************","**");// <------- Problem: Need to get list view's textview entries with the associated spinner. But its just not working. Always printing the same wrong textview data

               Log.v("Order Name",item._nText);
               Log.v("Order Count",item._cText);
               Log.v("Order Price",item._pText);

               Log.v("**********************","**");

           }
           @Override
           public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

           }
       }
   );


   }
   else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

  holder.rateSpinner = (Spinner)convertView.findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
  ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(c, 
                    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
  holder.rateSpinner.setAdapter(adapter);
  fItem item = getItem(position);



  holder.pView.setText(item._pText);
  holder.nView.setText(item._nText);
  holder.cView.setText(item._cText);


  return convertView;

}
```

The textViews in the list is loaded up first from a database. And then the user is asked to choose ratings from a spinner. After the user chooses the rating, I need to find the associated textView items and I don't understand how to get this row data out. See Print statement in the spinner's onItemSelectedListener()

Would really appreciate your help to figure this out.

Comment: To be clear : the Log.v prints the same textView item again and again for every spinner in the entire list

Comment: put this line `holder.personSpinner = (Spinner)convertView.findViewById(R.id.spinner2);` in IF

Comment: there seems two Spinners in your code while you say you have UI like : | textView | textView | textView | Spinner .. *what is holder.personSpinner and holder.rateSpinner?*

Comment: Sorry typo. I fixed it. I have the line in there already. There is only one spinner. rateSpinner. I was trying to make the variable names more meaningful before posting.

Comment: I even tried getting the textview data printed outside the Custom Adapter code. Let me post that.

Comment: A crappy way will be to create a new class `ViewHolder` with the 3 `TextViews` you want in, and set it in your `rateSpinner.setTag(...)`. In your listener, the view.getTag() should give you what you want.

Comment: Groco, can you show me the way even if crappy. What should I put in the setTag?

Comment: You put the views you want. To have the 3 views, create a new holder that manage the 3 views. Then holder.rateSpinner.setTag(myCrappyHolder)

Comment: Have you tried this solution?

Comment: Ok Groco what worked is this : holder.rateSpinner.setTag(item); and then in the onItemSelected I do : fw = (fItem) parent.getTag();  I know its not recommended to pass data through tags, but i don't know how else to accomplish this.

Comment: Thanks for understanding my issue and making a suggestion that helped me. Please let me know if you think this is a bad perf solution. My list could be very long. Its going to suck.

Answer (score 0):

When you create an adapter for you spinner you pass a list that is nowhere to be found in your given code.

Could it be that the list is always the same, that's why you're getting the same items for every spinner?

Comment: The UI looks like this : | textView | textView | textView | Spinner. I want to get the values in the 3 textviews after the user sets the spinner. Each textView has unique text in it. The code prints out the selected spinner items clearly. But it does not give me the correct textView data for each row inside the spinner's onItemSelectedListener

Answer (score 0):

just try this in your adapter

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder();
View vi = convertView;

if (vi == null) {
    vi = getContext().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.todolist_item, null);
    holder.pView = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.r1);
    holder.nView = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.r2);
    holder.cView = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.r3); 
    holder.rateSpinner = (Spinner)vi.findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
    holder.personSpinner = (Spinner)vi.findViewById(R.id.spinner2); 
    vi.setTag(holder);
}
else {
    holder = (ViewHolder) vi.getTag();
}

ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(c, 
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
holder.rateSpinner.setAdapter(adapter);
fItem item = getItem(position);

holder.pView.setText(item._pText);
holder.nView.setText(item._nText);
holder.cView.setText(item._cText);

return vi;
}
```

Comment: wanz : It's complaining here. Should this be a View or a LayoutInflater? vi = getContext().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.todolist_item, null); The error says the method getLayoutInflater() is undefined for a View

Comment: Wanz : There is no issue in the adapter painting the list view with rows of correct data. My issue is how to print the textView data inside the spinner's onClickSelectedItem listener

Comment: i'm trying clean your code and just try put the onClickSelectedItem listener after else { holder = (ViewHolder) vi.getTag();}